# Too few arguments to function (CodeIgniter, PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here's my problem. I've been saving data to DB then that error shows.

The error message

> "Message: Too few arguments to function
>   Model_properties::declare_existing_save(), 32 passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\amilyar\application\controllers\Applicant_properties.php
>   on line 113 and exactly 38 expected"

Here's my code under Model_properties

```
public function declare_existing_save($email,$tdn,$pin,$owner_name,$owner_address,$admin_name,$admin_address,$prop_no_street,$prop_barangay,$prop_province,$prop_cert,$prop_cadastral,$prop_ass_lot,$prop_bnorth,$prop_beast,$prop_bwest,$prop_bsouth,$with_ia,$ia_ow_total,$ia_as_total,$with_ib,$ib_ow_total,$ib_as_total,$with_ii,$ii_ow_total,$ii_as_total,$with_iiia,$iiia_ow_total,$iiia_as_total,$with_iiib,$iiib_ow_total,$iiib_as_total,$prop_id,$kind,$use,$mvalue,$level,$value){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO amilyar_properties (
        email,
        prop_record_type,
        prop_tdn,
        prop_pin,
        prop_owner,
        prop_owner_address,
        prop_name_of_admin,
        prop_name_of_admin_address,
        prop_no_street,
        prop_barangay,
        prop_province,
        prop_certificate_title_no,
        prop_cadastral_lot_no,
        prop_assessor_lot_no,
        prop_bound_north,
        prop_bound_east,
        prop_bound_west,
        prop_bound_south,
        prop_type_IA,
        ia_total,
        ia_as_total,
        prop_type_IB,
        ib_total,
        ib_as_total,
        prop_type_II,
        ii_total,
        ii_as_total,
        prop_type_IIIA,
        iiia_total,
        iiia_as_total,
        prop_type_IIIb,
        iiib_total,
        iiib_as_total,
        prop_approved,
        date_created
    ) VALUES (
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?
    )";
    $data = array(
        $email,
        2,
        $tdn,
        $pin,
        $owner_name,
        $owner_address,
        $admin_name,
        $admin_address,
        $prop_no_street,
        $prop_barangay,
        $prop_province,
        $prop_cert,
        $prop_cadastral,
        $prop_ass_lot,
        $prop_bnorth,
        $prop_beast,
        $prop_bwest,
        $prop_bsouth,    
        $with_ia, 
        $ia_ow_total,
        $ia_as_total,
        $with_ib,
        $ib_ow_total,
        $ib_as_total,
        $with_ii,
        $ii_ow_total,
        $ii_as_total,
        $with_iiia,
        $iiia_ow_total,
        $iiia_as_total,
        $with_iiib,
        $iiib_ow_total,
        $iiib_as_total,
        0,
        today()
    );
    $this->db->query($sql,$data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `amilyar_declaration_assessment`(`prop_id`, `asm_kind`, `asm_use`, `asm_mvalue`, `asm_level`, `asm_value`, `enabled`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $data = [$prop_id,$kind,$use,str_replace(",","",$mvalue),$level,str_replace(",","",$value),1];
        $query = $this->db->query($sql,$data);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();




}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about use an associative array as an argument to the function?

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. You have not provided all the arguments that the method requires. As @Eddie suggests, use an associative array before you go mad!!!

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
$createProperties = $this->Model_properties->createProperties(
    array(
        'email' => $email,
        'prop_record_type' => $prop_record_type,
        'prop_tdn' => $prop_tdn,
        'prop_pin' => $prop_pin,
        'prop_owner' => $prop_owner,
        'prop_owner_address' => $prop_owner_address,
        'prop_name_of_admin' => $prop_name_of_admin,
        'prop_name_of_admin_address' => $prop_name_of_admin_address,
        'prop_no_street' => $prop_no_street,
        'prop_barangay' => $prop_barangay,
        'prop_province' => $prop_province,
        'prop_certificate_title_no' => $prop_certificate_title_no,
        'prop_cadastral_lot_no' => $prop_cadastral_lot_no,
        'prop_assessor_lot_no' => $prop_assessor_lot_no,
        'prop_bound_north' => $prop_bound_north,
        'prop_bound_east' => $prop_bound_east,
        'prop_bound_west' => $prop_bound_west,
        'prop_bound_south' => $prop_bound_south,
        'prop_type_IA' => $prop_type_IA,
        'ia_total' => $ia_total,
        'ia_as_total' => $ia_as_total,
        'prop_type_IB' => $prop_type_IB,
        'ib_total' => $ib_total,
        'ib_as_total' => $ib_as_total,
        'prop_type_II' => $prop_type_II,
        'ii_total' => $ii_total,
        'ii_as_total' => $ii_as_total,
        'prop_type_IIIA' => $prop_type_IIIA,
        'iiia_total' => $iiia_total,
        'iiia_as_total' => $iiia_as_total,
        'prop_type_IIIb' => $prop_type_IIIb,
        'iiib_total' => $iiib_total,
        'iiib_as_total' => $iiib_as_total,
        'prop_approved' => $prop_approved,
        'date_created' => $date_created
    )
);

if($createProperties == false)
{
    echo 'Error: createProperties';
}
else
{
    echo 'Success: createProperties';
    $createDeclaration = $this->Model_properties->createDeclaration(
        array(
            'prop_id' => $email,
            'asm_kind' => $prop_record_type,
            'asm_use' => $prop_tdn,
            'asm_mvalue' => $prop_tdn,
            'asm_level' => $prop_tdn,
            'asm_value' => $prop_tdn,
            'enabled' => $prop_tdn
        )
    );

    if($createDeclaration == false)
    {
        echo 'Error: createDeclaration';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Success: createDeclaration';
    }
}
```

Model:

```
    public function createProperties($post)
    {
        $return = $this->db->insert('amilyar_properties', $post);
        return $return == true ? $this->db->insert_id() : false;
    }

    public function createDeclaration($post)
    {
        $return = $this->db->insert('amilyar_declaration_assessment', $post);
        return $return == true ? $this->db->insert_id() : false;
    }
```